# formControl maxlength - Eu quero mudar o valor do maxlength de acordo o valor selecionado

Tags: angular

Eu quero mudar o valor do maxlength do campo de acordo com o option selecionado

Por exemplo: cep o campo marcado de amarelo fica tamanho maximo 8

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

html

```
                <input
                    #tipoBuscaValorInput
                    (input)="tipoBuscaSelect.value == 'C' ? formatToCep(tipoBuscaValorInput) : ''"
                    autofocus
                    class="form-control form-control-sm"
                    formControlName="tipoBuscaValor"
                    id="tipoBuscaValor"
                    name="tipoBuscaValor"                
                    type="text"
                    maxlength="tipoBuscaSelect.value == 'C' ? '8' : '20'"
                />
```

typescript

```
 this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
        tipoBuscaValor: [""],
    });
```

Comment: Não gosto de falar assim, mas isso está bem errado!  Não use js nos atributos *HTML*, só funciona com eventos e depois que inventarão [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) javascript deve ficar restrito ao elemento [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) . No evento `change` do combobox `#tipoBuscaValorInput` faça a alteração no elemento alvo.

Comment: É exatamente como disse o Augusto, e isso é bem simples de fazer. Cria um método **`change()`** no `combobox` e vê qual a escolha do usuário, cria uma variável na classe do tipo number para controlar a propriedade **maxlength** e linka ela no Html por propertie bind assim `[maxlength]="maxLgth"` aí faz uma condicional no método change e atribui um valor  a variável conforme a condição, ex: `Se Cep maxLgth = 8`!

Comment: @LeAndrade Muito obrigada agora consegui entender.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode desenvolver por meio do [reactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

abaixo segue um exemplo de como usar o reactiveForms na funcionalidade que  você deseja no angular.

`app.component.ts`

```
 ...
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      tipoBuscaValor: [''],
      info: ['']
    })

  ...

  ngOnInit(){
    this.form.get('tipoBuscaValor')?.valueChanges.subscribe({

      next: (data) => {
        this.form.get('info')?.clearValidators();
        
        switch (data) {
          case 'cep':
            this.form.get('info')?.addValidators(Validators.maxLength(8))
            break;
          case 'inscricao_imobiliaria':
            this.form.get('info')?.addValidators(Validators.maxLength(20))
            break;
          case 'logradouro':
            this.form.get('info')?.addValidators(Validators.maxLength(20))
            break;  
          default:
            break;
        }

        this.form.get('info')?.updateValueAndValidity();
      }, 
      error: (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      },
    })

    this.form.get('info')?.valueChanges.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.result = (this.form.get('info')?.valid ? 'Valido': "Invalido")
      }
    })
  }
...
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <label >Tipo de busca</label>
    <select  formControlName="tipoBuscaValor" >
      <option value="cep"> Cep</option>
      <option value="inscricap_imobiliaria" > Inscrição Imobiliaria </option>
      <option value="logradouro" > Logradouro </option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="info" >
  </div>
  <span>
    {{result}}
  </span>

</form>
```